# How to tranpose a large daily financial dataset from wide to a long format of on R?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, tidyverse

I'm have a daily bond dataset with different maturities on wide format, organized, for each maturity, with a column for the date of observation, other with information of the interest rate and a third with bond maturity. As bonds has different maturities, there is NA values when the data is not available. I'm trying to change this data frame to a long format, where we have one stacked column for the "reference date", other for the "yield" and a third one for the "maturity", dropping the NA observations. I've tried to use pivot longer, but didn't succeeded. Can you help me with this?

I have something like this:

| Ref_date1 | Yield1 | Maturity1 | Ref_date2 | Yield2 | Maturity2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 3.27 | date1 | 2023-01-01 | 3.47 | date2 |
| 2023-01-02 | 3.25 | date1 | 2023-01-02 | 3.45 | date2 |
| 2023-01-03 | 3.26 | date1 | 2023-01-03 | 3.46 | date2 |
| 2023-01-04 | 3.28 | date1 | 2023-01-04 | 3.48 | date2 |
| 2023-01-05 | 3.23 | date1 | 2023-01-05 | 3.43 | date2 |
| 2023-01-06 | 3.22 | date1 | 2023-01-06 | 3.42 | date2 |
| 2023-01-07 | 3.21 | date1 | 2023-01-07 | 3.41 | date2 |
| 2023-01-08 | 3.29 | date1 | 2023-01-08 | NA | date2 |
| 2023-01-09 | 3.25 | date1 |  |  |  |

And was expecting to get something like this

| ref_date | yield | maturity | mem_date | mem_yield |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 3.27 | date1 | Ref_date1 | yield1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 3.47 | date2 | Ref_date2 | yield2 |
| 2023-01-02 | 3.25 | date1 | Ref_date1 | yield1 |
| 2023-01-03 | 3.46 | date2 | Ref_date2 | yield2 |
| 2023-01-04 | 3.28 | date1 | Ref_date1 | yield1 |
| 2023-01-04 | 3.48 | date2 | Ref_date2 | yield2 |
| 2023-01-05 | 3.23 | date1 | Ref_date1 | yield1 |
| 2023-01-05 | 3.43 | date2 | Ref_date2 | yield2 |
| 2023-01-06 | 3.22 | date1 | Ref_date1 | yield1 |
| 2023-01-06 | 3.42 | date2 | Ref_date2 | yield2 |
| 2023-01-07 | 3.21 | date1 | Ref_date1 | yield1 |
| 2023-01-07 | 3.41 | date2 | Ref_date2 | yield2 |
| 2023-01-08 | 3.29 | date1 | Ref_date1 | yield1 |
| 2023-01-09 | 3.25 | date1 | Ref_date1 | yield1 |

I'm using

```
x4_w <- pivot_longer(x4_vcto,cols = everything(), 
                     names_to = c("mem_date", "mem_yield", "maturity",
                     values_to = c("ref_date","yield", values_drop_na=TRUE)
```

Comment: does `reshape(df, 1:6, dir='long', sep="")` get you somewhere? I am unable to tell where the `mem_date` and `mem_yield` are comming from

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```
 reshape(df, seq(ncol(df)), dir='long', sep="")|>
    transform(mem_date = paste0('Ref_date', time),
                        mem_yield = paste0('yield', time))

    time   Ref_date Yield Maturity id  mem_date mem_yield
1.1    1 2023-01-01  3.27    date1  1 Ref_date1    yield1
2.1    1 2023-01-02  3.25    date1  2 Ref_date1    yield1
3.1    1 2023-01-03  3.26    date1  3 Ref_date1    yield1
4.1    1 2023-01-04  3.28    date1  4 Ref_date1    yield1
5.1    1 2023-01-05  3.23    date1  5 Ref_date1    yield1
6.1    1 2023-01-06  3.22    date1  6 Ref_date1    yield1
7.1    1 2023-01-07  3.21    date1  7 Ref_date1    yield1
8.1    1 2023-01-08  3.29    date1  8 Ref_date1    yield1
9.1    1 2023-01-09  3.25    date1  9 Ref_date1    yield1
1.2    2 2023-01-01  3.47    date2  1 Ref_date2    yield2
2.2    2 2023-01-02  3.45    date2  2 Ref_date2    yield2
3.2    2 2023-01-03  3.46    date2  3 Ref_date2    yield2
4.2    2 2023-01-04  3.48    date2  4 Ref_date2    yield2
5.2    2 2023-01-05  3.43    date2  5 Ref_date2    yield2
6.2    2 2023-01-06  3.42    date2  6 Ref_date2    yield2
7.2    2 2023-01-07  3.41    date2  7 Ref_date2    yield2
8.2    2 2023-01-08    NA    date2  8 Ref_date2    yield2
```

---

same code in tidyverse:

```
df %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c('.value', "time"), 
                             names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)") %>%
    mutate(mem_date = paste0('Ref_date', time),
                 mem_yield = paste0('yield', time))

# A tibble: 18 × 6
   time  Ref_date   Yield Maturity mem_date  mem_yield
   <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    
 1 1     2023-01-01  3.27 date1    Ref_date1 yield1   
 2 2     2023-01-01  3.47 date2    Ref_date2 yield2   
 3 1     2023-01-02  3.25 date1    Ref_date1 yield1   
 4 2     2023-01-02  3.45 date2    Ref_date2 yield2   
 5 1     2023-01-03  3.26 date1    Ref_date1 yield1   
 6 2     2023-01-03  3.46 date2    Ref_date2 yield2   
 7 1     2023-01-04  3.28 date1    Ref_date1 yield1   
 8 2     2023-01-04  3.48 date2    Ref_date2 yield2   
 9 1     2023-01-05  3.23 date1    Ref_date1 yield1   
10 2     2023-01-05  3.43 date2    Ref_date2 yield2   
11 1     2023-01-06  3.22 date1    Ref_date1 yield1   
12 2     2023-01-06  3.42 date2    Ref_date2 yield2   
13 1     2023-01-07  3.21 date1    Ref_date1 yield1   
14 2     2023-01-07  3.41 date2    Ref_date2 yield2   
15 1     2023-01-08  3.29 date1    Ref_date1 yield1   
16 2     2023-01-08 NA    date2    Ref_date2 yield2   
17 1     2023-01-09  3.25 date1    Ref_date1 yield1   
18 2     NA         NA    NA       Ref_date2 yield2
```